# Call node from C# .NET Standard class library

Tags: c#, node.js, npm, class-library

I'm trying to build a C# wrapper library for the [MJML framework](https://mjml.io/).

When run "by hand", the mjml framework tends to be used through a powershell or a bash script that does a bit of random stuff that I couldn't understand, but that obviously shadows a call to `node node_modules/mjml/bin/mjml`.

Do I have any way to locally install node and run the command from within a C# class library ? Do I have to use a bash call using for example `System.Diagnostics.Process` ? I looked through the web but all I found was [edgejs](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) and it seems to be both overkill and not really designed to do that.